# Preserving newline in find/grep search results

Tags: bash, grep, find, newlines

I am recursively searching for the occurrence of php scripts being called from other files using the following script.

```
find . -exec grep -Hn $1 {} \; | grep -v ^Binary;
```

Works great!  Now, I need the returned results to determine the action to be taken next.

```
r=$(find . -exec grep -Hn $str {} \; | grep -v ^Binary;)

 if [ -z "$r" ];
    then
          Do this
    else
          Do something else
    fi
```

PROBLEM:  By it's self the find script returns the results, each on a new line.

```
./path/to/file.php
./path/to/another_file.php
./path/to/third_file.php
```

However, when assigning the output to the $r variable, the newline character is not preserved and the results are printed on one line making it difficult to read.

```
./path/to/file.php ./path/to/file.php ./path/to/third_file.php
```

How do I preserve the newline character while assigning the output into a variable?

Comment: Are you sure that the newlines are not preserved when ***assigning*** the text to the variable? Are you saying `echo $r` or `echo "$r"`? If you're saying `echo $r`, then the newlines are getting stripped *on output*.

Answer (score 9):

You don't show what you do with `$r`, but I bet it's

```
echo $r
```

You need to enclose the variable in double quotes to preserve the newlines

```
echo "$r"
```

Unquoted, the variable is subject to [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting), where any sequences of whitespace <sup>1</sup> (including newlines) are replaced by a single space <sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup>: by default, depends on the contents of `$IFS` (default: space, tab, newline)

Comment: I'm outputing the $r to a 'hits.txt' file.  Ah yes, "$r" made the difference.  Thanks!